# jQuery javascript way of checking if some html exist on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before appending more code, I want to make sure:

```
<a href='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36'>Hello</a>
```

isn't already on the html page inside the div where id='faqs'

```
<div id='faqs'>
<a href='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36'>Hello</a>
</div>
```

What is the best way of doing this with jquery or javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use jQuery to select the element, and check the `length` property of the resulting object:

```
var anchor = $('#faqs a[href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36"]')
if(anchor.length == 0) {
    // element isn't on the page
}
```

Comment: I can't search the exact way its it in the html?

Comment: @milan I suppose you could, but I don't see why you *would*. Checking HTML strings just seems like a considerably less efficient, and more error prone, method of checking if the element exists.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to end up with the a tag as a child in the div tag, and thats it, then don't bother checking, just re add it, like this:

```
$('#faqs').html('');
$('<a />')
  .attr('href', 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36')
  .html('hello')
  .appendTo($('#faqs'))​;​
```

However, if you genuinely need to check if it exists, then you can do something like this:

```
var exists = $('#faqs a[href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36"]').length > 0;
```

UPDATE

Finding the string in the html can be done as follows, but this is not a recommended solution. You may run into issues with different browsers encoding html in different ways etc (tested in chrome):

```
var stringToFind = '<a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36">Hello</a>';

// need to replace the & ...
stringToFind = stringToFind.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');

var exists = $('#faqs').html().indexOf(stringToFind) > -1;
if (exists) {
  // do something            
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Here's a working example -> http://jsfiddle.net/Uzef8/2/

Comment: I do need to genuinely check if it exist, do you know of a way I can do it without breaking up my string?

Comment: What do you mean 'without breaking up my string'? Please elaborate

Comment: I would like to search for: <a href='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36'>Hello</a> exactly as is.

Comment: That's a weird requirement, but an approach like @nycynik suggested would probably be the best way, by using indexOf. I will update my answer with my interpretation

Answer (score 0):

You could search using indexOf

```
var inBlock = $('#faqs').html();
if (inBlock.indexOf("<a href='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36'>Hello</a>") == -1) {
    $('#faqs').append ("<a href='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36'>Hello</a>");
}
```

Comment: this does not work and  I think it's because the .html() does not return anything i append to that div.

Comment: you might need to change the location where it runs.  Is it in the document ready function now?

Comment: think the problem is html encoding issue. .html() will return & as &amp;

Comment: your answer includes that conversion, and I agree its an issue.  Might be better to track ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('a[href$="view=article&id=36"]', '#faqs').length) {
    //does'nt exist
}
```